# Media query not working with all android devices

Tags: android, ios, css, mobile, media-queries

I really hope this question has not been answered because I could not find it anywhere...  I have a site that uses media queries to present different data if it is a mobile or not.  I also have a mobile app with a webview that calls the site.   It works on all iOS devices, but only works on some Android devices...  Do some android devices not implement media queries in a webview?

Here is my CSS Media Queries:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
    #mobileBody { display:inline; }
    #header, .wrapper, #footer { display: none; }
    body { background:none; background-color:black; }
    .mobileLogo { width: 85%; margin:50% auto 0; }
    .mobileLogo a img { width: 100%; }
    .mobile_fb_login { width: 50%; margin:10% auto 0; }
    .mobile_fb_login a img { width: 100%; }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
    #mobileBody { display:inline; }
    #header, .wrapper, #footer { display: none; }
    body { background:none; background-color:black; }
    .mobileLogo { width: 85%; margin:10% auto 0; }
    .mobileLogo a img { width: 100%; }
    .mobile_fb_login { width: 50%; margin:10% auto 0; }
    .mobile_fb_login a img { width: 100%; }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 321px) and (max-device-width : 568px) {
    #mobileBody { display:inline; }
    #header, .wrapper, #footer { display: none; }
    body { background:none; background-color:black; }
    .mobileLogo { width: 85%; margin:10% auto 0; }
    .mobileLogo a img { width: 100%; }
    .mobile_fb_login { width: 50%; margin:10% auto 0; }
    .mobile_fb_login a img { width: 100%; }
}


@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 569px) and (max-device-width : 767px) {
    #mobileBody { display:inline; }
    #header, .wrapper, #footer { display: none; }
    body { background:none; background-color:black; }
    .mobileLogo { width: 85%; margin:40% auto 0; }
    .mobileLogo a img { width: 100%; }
    .mobile_fb_login { width: 50%; margin:10% auto 0; }
    .mobile_fb_login a img { width: 100%; }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait ) {
    #mobileBody { display:inline; }
    #header, .wrapper, #footer { display: none; }
    body { background:none; background-color:black; }
    .mobileLogo { width: 85%; margin:40% auto 0; }
    .mobileLogo a img { width: 100%; }
    .mobile_fb_login { width: 50%; margin:10% auto 0; }
    .mobile_fb_login a img { width: 100%; }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    #mobileBody { display:inline; }
    #header, .wrapper, #footer { display: none; }
    body { background:none; background-color:black; }
    .mobileLogo { width: 85%; margin:10% auto 0 !important; }
    .mobileLogo a img { width: 100%; }
    .mobile_fb_login { width: 50%; margin:10% auto 0; }
    .mobile_fb_login a img { width: 100%; }
}
```

Please help if you can :-)

Comment: Do you know what android devices/browsers are not working?

Comment: tmobile mytouch, Samsung galaxy s4 and Samsung galaxy s2 did not work... but a Galaxy S3 and S1 did And so did my Android Emulator...

Comment: Some android browsers and likely webviews scale pages in a way that creates false values for media queries. Can you post your viewport meta tag?

Comment: My meta tag is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Ok narrowing this down... When you say it "doesn't work" do you mean that it loads the full site instead of the mobile site or that it loads the mobile site but the media queries don't apply properly? I am thinking it may have to do with screen density.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Each device does one of each. The mytouch loads the desktop version. On the galaxy s4 the media query shows the mobile version but does not scale properly.